# MySQL - Order by one field until results empty then order by another field

Tags: mysql

I have a table `specimen` which contains a field `room`. I want to order the records by `room` while `room == 'f'`, then the remaining records order by `topography_index`. How can I do this in the MySQL query?

Comment: If you order records by `room` while `room = 'f'`, then nothing will be ordered since all the values are the same.

Comment: room can be in the range of a,b,c,d,e or f....so I just want to have specimens with room 'f' at the top, and then order by topography_index for the rest...hope that makes senses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
Select * From YourTable 
Order By (Case When Room = 'f' Then 0 Else 1 End),topography_index
```

you can replace 1 with maxi number

Answer (score 2):

Vignesh's solution is fine.  An easier way to write it in MySQL is:

```
order by (room = 'f') desc, topography_index
```

MySQL has the nice feature that it treats boolean results as integers, with `0` for false and `1` for true.